# Ho to get only columns that have value in a specefic line lower than value in one of other lines in R

Tags: r, statistics, multiple-columns, rows, data-manipulation

I have data like this

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4 c5 C6 C7   C8
A   5  7  10  1  3  2 14  2
B   3  7  12  2  10 5  8  3
C   2  5  20  2  5  5  8  10
D  10  4  18  5  7  4 18  19
```

I want only the columns that have value in line D lower than values in at least one of the columns

So the result i want is

```
     C2  C3  C5  C6 
A    7  10   3   2 
B    7  12  10   5  
C    5  20   5   5   
D    4  18   7   4
```

Also i want to obtain only colulmns that have value in a row D lower than value in rows B and C

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain me why C2 remains in your result?

Comment: Because C is lower than the other rows (i want to get columns where D is lower than one of the other rows or all the other rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` on each column. Check if the value for "D" is less than at least one value in the same column. This assumes that "A"-"D" in the example are rownames.

```
df[apply(
  df,
  2,
  function(x) {
    any(x[["D"]] < x)
  }
)]
```

**Output**

```
  C2 C3 c5 C6
A  7 10  3  2
B  7 12 10  5
C  5 20  5  5
D  4 18  7  4
```

Comment: Thanj you for your anwser, can you tell me please how can i specify only some rows for example if i want to get only columns that have value in a specefic row lower than values in other specefic rows for example only columns that have value in row "D" lower than values in rows B and C, thank you

Comment: Try something like `any(x[["D"]] < x[c("B", "C")])` in the function. There you can subset a column based on specific rownames. This assumes that "D" is less than at least one value from "B" or "C". If you want "D" that is less than both "B" and "C" you can remove `any`...